# PHP Unirest plugin not working properly

Tags: php, json, mongodb, http

I use [Unirest for PHP](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php) to do some HTTP Requests. Everything works fine, until I want to pass a fairly complex JSON to my Node.js router.

First I do a GET request that returns a JSON Object, then I extend this JSON object (needs to be done, I know it sucks) and want to feed it back into my other http POST request... and here is where the trouble starts:

I echoed the JSON that is returned and copied the output into postman -> works fine. If I want use the JSON directly in PHP in next request:

$teamsMemberOf is the variable which is containing the GET response.

```
$headers = array("Accept" => "application/json");
$newBody = '{"team":'.$teamsMemberOf->raw_body.'}';
$relevantBoxesAmount = Unirest\Request::post("http://localhost:3001/my/route/".$result['_id']."/get-something-from-server", $headers, $newBody);
```

and it doesn't work.
Error is 500 and 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' which is certainly related to something in the JSON object.

Does someone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Could you post output of `var_dump($teamsMemberOf->raw_body);`?

Comment: its pretty long...http://pastebin.com/Z5wXFDrQ

Comment: If I echo $newBody and simply paste everything into postman, it works perfectly. I'm desperate >-< I need to get this working...

Comment: Have you tried decoding `$newBody` using `json_decode()` before passing it to `Request::post()`?

Comment: yes, its not working: HTTP error 500, 'cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: Then maybe there's something wrong with your Node.JS router? Have you tried sending this request to `http://mockbin.com/request`?

Comment: Also, 5xx errors are not client, but server errors.

Comment: well, it is working with postman (https://www.getpostman.com) using the exact output from my first GET request (I echoed raw_body and paste it into postman)... thats why I don't think that there is a server problem. I assume something is going wrong during conversion but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101222/discussion-between-chakuze-and-gothdo).